# Python...Lambda not working?

Tags: python, lambda

I was going through the Python tutorials and I decided to create a little exercise for myself with the "Lambda" tool. It's a basic square root calculator. However, when I try to run it, it doesn't return a number. Here's how it looks so far.

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter number:"))

def power(n):
    return lambda x: x**n

sqrt = power(0.5)

sqrt(x)
```

Why doesn't it work? If I've done made some sort of horrible mistake, please alert me. Remember, I'm a newbie so no complicated language please.

Comment: What python version are you using ? It works just fine here on Python 2.7.2

Comment: That's weird...I'm also using Python 2.7.2 and it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Entering `4` returns `2.0`, as I would expect.

Comment: @Davy8 Yes, I know, I'm not THAT much of a newbie. ;) It just said "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes" though when I tried to do it though.

Comment: Why in hell would you do that when you can use `math.sqrt`

Comment: @Franklin It was just an exercise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by it doesn't work? Did you just forget to do:

```
print sqrt(x)
```

instead of just

```
sqrt(x)
```

?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct program. I think you forgot to print the result.
Change last line to

```
print sqrt(x)
```

and you should get what you want.